# Vimperator-like addon for Internet Explorer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, vimperator

Is there a [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator)-like add-in for Internet Explorer?
More specifically I'm looking for something similar to the [QuickHint](http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/hints.xhtml) feature of Vimperator:

1. You hit some predefined key and every link (or every click-able control, I'm not sure) in the page is given a number.
2. Typing this number is equivalent to clicking the link

(Or maybe some javascript code that could be used with a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)-like add-in for IE)